# How can I show the fade in animation and countdowntimer one time for each textview?

Tags: java, android, animation, textview, countdowntimer

I'm making a text-based game with Android Studio. 
This is the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final TextView txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    final TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    final TextView txt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    final ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(GameActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
            txt1.startAnimation(fadeIn);

            Animation fadeIn2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(GameActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
            txt2.startAnimation(fadeIn2);

            txt1.setText("Text");
            txt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt2.setText("Text");
            txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }.start();

    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){}

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){
            Animation fadeIn_img = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(GameActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
            img1.startAnimation(fadeIn_img);

            Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(GameActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
            txt3.startAnimation(fadeIn);

            Animation fadeIn2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(GameActivity.this, R.anim.fadein);
            txt4.startAnimation(fadeIn2);

            img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
            txt3.setText("Text");
            txt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt4.setText("Text");
            txt4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }.start();
```

I want the animation and the countdowntimer to work only one time for each textview. When I restart the game the textviews have to display without anything.
It is like a list of textviews that display in succession every 2 seconds. When the user close and then restart the application, he has to find the state where he had finished. 
How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like a fainting textviews right? Heres an example

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout Container;
    ArrayList<View> textList = new ArrayList<>();

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Container);

        for (int i = 0; i < Container.getChildCount(); i++) {
            textList.add(Container.getChildAt(i));
        }

        fadeView(textList.get(0));
    }

    private void fadeView(final View view) { 
        final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        count++;

        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (count == textList.size()) return;
                fadeView(textList.get(count));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
        });

        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }  
}
```

fadein.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:fromAlpha="1.0"
  android:repeatCount="0"
  android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is first"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is second"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is third"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Just make sure to put all your views (in this case textviews) inside an array to make it clean and proper.
Hope it helps. Cheers Happy codings.

Comment: Thanks, your code is even better. Do you know how can I save the game? Because when I close and restart the application, textviews always start over. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can search for Preference or SQLite for that. You can start reading on here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html